# import BeamMusicPlayer to my project

Tags: xcode, import

I downloaded the [BeamMusicPlayer](https://github.com/BeamApp/MusicPlayerViewController) from git and dragged the `.xcodeproj` into my project target and all that worked fine but when I try to import `BeamMusicPlayerViewController.h` to the existing project xcode says the file can't be found.

Screenshot of the library successfully added to my project:
[image]

I don't understand why I'm not able to import the BeamMusicPlayer header files to my project. Does anyone know why?

** EDIT ** 
I checked my library search paths and even added the BeamMusicPlayer folder explicity but it didn't help.

Comment: did you try using cocoapods ?
http://cocoapods.org
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2

add the dependency pod 'BeamMusicPlayerViewController' in your podfile
run pod install

Comment: I've never used cocoapods before but it sounds like I'll have to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked once I used cocoapods to install the desired library. [You can learn how to install cocoapods here.](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) I'm still put-out that I couldn't figure out how to install this without cocoapods AND I'm finding out that uninstalling a library added with cocoapods is more of a pain than it's worth.